# pandas rolling function with Lamdba

Tags: pandas, lambda, rolling-computation

I was working on the older pandas 0.24.0 version where I had code:

```
df["A"] = df['B'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])
```

However the pandas version was upgraded to 1.1.0, which causes this code to not work.
I tried using different variations of rolling function with expanding as well.

Can someone help write the above line of code to work in **pandas 1.1.0**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like `shift`

```
df['A'] = df['B'] - df['B'].shift()
```